# MySQL procedure syntax error, how to assign a value to the concated variable?

Tags: mysql, variables, procedure

```
DECLARE LENGTH INT(20) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE DIM_0 VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE DIM_1 VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE DIM_2 VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE DIM_3 VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE DIM_4 VARCHAR(255);

SET LENGTH = F_DIM_ITEM_NUM(DIM_I);
DECLARE i int(20) DEFAULT 0;
WHILE i < LENGTH
DO 
    SET concat('DIM_',i) = F_DIM_ITEM_GET(DIM_I, i + 1);
    SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
```

It seems the return of Function F_DIM_ITEM_GET doesn't assign to the var DIM_i,
or there are others mistakes. How can I make it work? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: At a quick glance, you are trying to change the MySQL code at runtime I believe. You need to use [Dynamic SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to do the job. `SET concat('DIM_', i) = F_DIM_ITEM_GET(DIM_I, i + 1);` does not change the code itself e.g `SET DIM_1 = F_DIM_ITEM_GET(DIM_I, i + 1);` which is what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you @JonathonOgden it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat('DIM_',i)` is not a variable, but a string literal (constant) and you cannot assign value to it. You can try to use [dynamic sql through prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to create the sql statement to be executed dynamically using string concatenation and then execute it.

Create the sql dynamically (obviously, declare the DSQL variable first), execute it, and free it up:

```
DSQL = 'SET ' + concat('DIM_',i) + '= F_DIM_ITEM_GET(DIM_I, i + 1)';
PREPARE stmt FROM DSQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

You also need to declare the `i` variable before using it.